# Whats the purpose of BaseTemplateName, BaseTemplateID and BaseConfigurationID? (Sharepoint)

Tags: sharepoint

What does BaseTemplateName, BaseTemplateID and BaseConfigurationID exacly do? Whats purpose of them in the webtemplate elements.xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BaseTemplateName** - comes from the out-of-the-box site template that you want your web template to be based on (it can be STS, SRCHCEN, ...)

**BaseTemplateID** - along with an abrevated name, you will also have to provide the base site template ID ( 1 - for STS, 50 - for SRCHCEN)

**BaseConfigurationID** - it's the configuration ID. Every site template can have more than one configuration (for web templates you can have only one - 0). For example in case the base template is STS you can have config 0, 1 or 2 corresponding to Team Site, Blank Site and Document Workspace.

Check the following [link http://blumenthalit.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=45](http://blumenthalit.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=45)